# Source R from bitbucket private snippet

Tags: r, bitbucket, rcurl, devtools, httr

I want to source a R script file I have created in bitbucket as snippet. When I used `source_url` from `devtools` package, I need to pass sha1 value which I don't know where to find. I tried some functions from `RCurl` and `httr`, but Could not source the script file. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the  sha1 value. You can source bitbucket's snippets just with **the url of the raw file** (in the snippet push the button RAW on the desired file, and then copy the url from the address bar). But **the snippet should be public**, if it is private you cannot access it.

For example, for this silly snippet: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/anpefi/q8g69

I get the Url for the raw kk.R file as https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/anpefi/q8g69/4ca5ac49e4e3535dfdc85949ac20408aeed97567/files/kk.R

then,

```
> x <- 0
> source_url("https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/anpefi/q8g69/4ca5ac49e4e3535dfdc85949ac20408aeed97567/files/kk.R")
SHA-1 hash of file is 9a56cd15e13986bc8699560759225ade199c17f7
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If I set the snippet as private, this doesn't work.

[Edited]
Anyway, if you want the sha-1 of the file, **download it and get the sha1 locally with sha1sum (in Linux)**. Alternatively, **you can set the snippet public for a moment, apply the above code to get the sha1 in the output and then make the snippet private again**.

Ok, editing again. I just realized that yes, you can source a private snippet with the sha1.

Comment: Edited to add the answer to how to get the sha1 of the file anyway.

Comment: Edited again, as I realized that it is true that using the sha1 you can source a private snippet. So I emphatized the ways to get the sha1.

Comment: Is there anyway to find sha for the snippet file? I don't have linux system. Is it available on bitbucket file online?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot get the sha1 directly in bitbucket. You already can use the alternative way I wrote in the answer. This is, in bitbucket go to your snippet and press edit. Do not change anything but the permissions, set them to public (don't worry, it is just for a while). Save it and then open your R session. Run the command: `source_url("URL_OF_YOUR_SNIPPET")` in the output you will see the sha1 (like in the example in my answer). Then you can come back to bitbucket and change the permissions of your snippet back to private (but don't change the file, or the sha1 will change).